# Finding top X shortest path in complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I understand that Dijikstra algorithm would give me the shortest path in the graph. However, say i would like to find the top x number of shortest path in the graph. Would there be any algorithms to solve that issue?

I have found a solution but i didnt really understand the data files.

heres a link to my question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017527/yen-implementation-of-shortest-path

Comment: Please provide more information: Single source? Single destination? Directed or undirected? Any other specifics you are interested in like sparse or dense, weighted or unweighted, etc.

Comment: @Imran i have edited my question to reflect.

Comment: The final link to the paper http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/martins00new.html seems to be broken. Is a comprehensive presentation of the problem and the algorithm available? A different question coming up immediately is time complexity. As I understand the problem, the length of the output may grow exponentially in the size of the input, as the number of shortest paths may grow exponentially in the number of nodes.

Comment: Have a look at [Eppstein's paper](http://pdf.aminer.org/001/059/121/finding_the_k_shortest_paths.pdf).